# Edit names of image database with batch files

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a folder with 460 images with 23 per person in the format: `image_0001.jpg` to `image_0460.jpg`.
What is the batch command to rename them in the form `01-01.jpg` to `01-23.jpg` for a person and thus the entire database upto `20-23.jpg`?
[EDIT]
I came across:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *') do (
  if not "%%~nxi"=="%~nx0" (
    ren "%%i" "!a!" 
    set /a a+=1
 ) 
)
```

I could not find a way to use loop variables to do the same. Is there a way to use loop variables or is there another way?

Comment: You say `"a folder"` but then use a recursive `/r`.  Is this a single folder or a tree of folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET /a filenum=10000
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,20) DO (
 FOR /L %%b IN (1,1,23) DO (
  SET /a filenum+=1
  SET /a newnum=10000+%%b+(%%a*100^)
  ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\image_!filenum:~-4!.jpg" "!newnum:~1,2!-!newnum:~-2!".jpg
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

The issue is one of leading zeroes, hence invoke delayedexpansion and calculate using 10000+a significant number, then substring.

The rest is simply a matter of mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

This method use the `%` (modulus or remainder) operator to count in groups of 23: the `image=(image+1)%23` part vary `image` variable from 0 to 22 and repeat this count. `imgaux=101+image` vary `imgaux` from 101 to 123 and just the last two digits are used in the `ren` command. Finally, `person+=!image` increment `person` variable each time that `image` is zero.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A person=100, image=-1
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
   set /A "image=(image+1)%%23, imgaux=101+image, person+=^!image"
   ECHO ren "%%a" "!person:~1!-!imgaux:~1!.jpg"
)
```

Note that in this method the number of persons doesn't need to be known in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was using your script to delete certain files from different database. How did you manage to get 01 instead of 1 in your method? I'm new to batch files so sorry asking such detailed questions.

Comment: When `image=0`, then `set /A imgaux=101+image` assign `101` to imgaux. The substring extraction `!imgaux:~1!` get from the _second_ character on (character numeration in substring extraction start at zero), so `01` is used...